# Detect if a file is a duplicate and rename it if not

Tags: language-agnostic, file-handling

I have some code that moves files to the same directory. What would be a good strategy to:

- Detect if a file is a duplicate of an existing file in the directory? This is to decide whether to delete the source or simply leave it.
- Rename the source file if a destination file with the same name but different content already exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Detect duplicate files?

Most programming languages will have a function called something similar to `FileExists` taking a filename and returning a boolean indicating whether a file with the given name exists on the file system.

> Handle files which have identical names but different content?

Calculate a [SHA1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) checksum for both files and compare those hashes. Once again most languages will have a sha1 function taking an array of bytes representing the contents of the files and returning an array of bytes representing the SHA1 hash.

Comment: I'm testing if the destination file already exists. What I'd like to do is the following. If the destination file exists and is identical, simply ignore the source file. If the destination file exists but has different content, apply a consistant renaming algorithm and keep a trace of the original file name in XML or in a DB.

Answer (score 1):

Well, an easy way to do it is to do a [cyclic redundancy check](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check). Several languages have functions for this implemented. You can also calculate the md5 sum for your files. This is not 100% reliable though.

If you need to check if they are IDENTICAL, you need to open up a stream to both files, and compare them byte by byte.

The check for duplicate filenames are obvious, compare them.

Edit: If you have many files, compare the file size. If it does not match, they cannot be equal.

Comment: Thanks alexn. Why is CRC32 and MD5 not a 100% reliable? I'm currently using md5 to check if a file has been copied properly as a failsafe. I was also thinking of having a list of MD5s to check against when a file is added. However, this approach could become inefficient if there is a large number of files. This could be solved by using an algorithm to reduce the number of comparisons. As for identical filenames, I'd like to keep a trace of the original filename (perhaps in a DB) and copy it under another name.

Comment: They can cause collisions. How large set of files are you dealing with?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the original file names, as a handy way, just calculate MD5 or SHA1 hash of the file "content" and rename the file to it. :-)

Comment: That's not a bad idea. It would make the file names less human readable but it would avoid duplicate names. Also, if there's a collision as alexn has explained a suffix could be added.